# SOAP Service Calls (Content Too Large Error)

Tags: soap, google-apps-script

Sorry to bother you with this question, but I have a question regarding quota limits in Google Apps Script. Specifically, I would like to know what the maximum size is that a SOAP response can be. We have a fairly large SOAP response, and Google Apps Script produces a **Content Too Large** error.

Does anyone have any idea what the maximum size is of a SOAP response? I've tried to look on the Google Apps Scripting Dashboard, but could not find any conclusive answer to help me any further.

We have a Google Apps Enterprise account, I guess it makes a difference in terms of quotas e.t.c.

Does anyone of you also have any idea if there is a possibility to circumvene this error? Or are there any other specific methods that you like to use to get the result that you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some tests with SoapUI to gather more information about how many megabytes are being pulled in, I came to the conclusion that the limit for SOAP calls is 10MB.